# Flutter keep certain elements fixed during scrolling?

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-layout, flutter-listview, singlechildscrollview

How to keep some elements fixed (and above scrollable parts) during scroll?
Does it need to be inside a SingleChildScrollView?

Made a visual example of my problem:

I need the blue part to be scrollable, and that it goes behind the green part that needs to stay fixed.

[image: How to keep certain elements fixed during scrolling?]

**This is a simplified part of my code:**

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Obx(()=>Container(THIS CONTAINER SHOULD STAY FIXED DURING SCROLL)),
              Obx(()=>Column(THIS PART SHOULD BE SCROLLABLE)),
              Obx(()=>Text(THIS PART SHOULD BE SCROLLABLE)),
              Obx(()=>Row(THIS PART SHOULD BE SCROLLABLE))
            ],
          )
        ),
```

Comment: you can use appBar of sliverAppBar for this

Comment: but my container is inside ListView, I guess I can move it up

Comment: yeah you have to move it up from the scrollView

Comment: and you are using two scroll controls listView and singleChildScrollView

Comment: Wrap your ListView with Column, then move your container above the ListView and remove SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: Wrapping in ListView doesn't work, part that should be scrollable isn't visible

Comment: have you tried put your listview and fixed container in a column? for example: `Column(children: [ FixedContainer(), Expanded(child: ListView())])`

Comment: @Eray this works, thanks, you should post this as an answer, so I could check it as correct

Comment: @MunsifAli tried adding it to the AppBar, but it doesn't look great, edit: AppBar height is the issue, and my container isn't stretching fully across the screen

Comment: check out his project i have created the Appbar like that in it https://github.com/Munsif-Ali/StackOverflow-Question-Ui

Comment: lack of flexibleSpace is probably why it didn't look good

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put your ListView widget and FixedContainer widget in a Column, it will work.

For example:

```
 Column(
    children: [
       Obx(()=>Container(THIS CONTAINER SHOULD STAY FIXED DURING SCROLL)),
       Expanded(
           child: ListView(
              Obx(()=>Column(THIS PART SHOULD BE SCROLLABLE)),
              Obx(()=>Text(THIS PART SHOULD BE SCROLLABLE)),
              Obx(()=>Row(THIS PART SHOULD BE SCROLLABLE)),
           ),
       ),
    ],
 )
```